# if / then statement for currency in python

Tags: python, dataframe, if-statement

Trying to convert currency in a `df` using python.
I have two columns: price and currency.
I tried to use `if/elif/else` statements but I'm doing something wrong.

```
Sample of df: 
|price|currency|boat type| year built|
|-----|--------|---------|-----------|
|3490 |EUR     |console  | 2020      |
|2299 |EUR     |fishing  | 2019      |
|3500 |CHF     |fishing  | 1987      |
|4600 |Â£      |runabout | 2020      |
```

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you

Code I've tried...

```
if drop_boats['Currency'] == 'EUR':
    drop_boats['Price'] = drop_boats['Price'] * 1.10 
elif drop_boats['Currency'] == 'CHF':
    drop_boats['Price'] = drop_boats['Price'] * 1.08 
elif drop_boats['Currency'] == 'DKK':
    drop_boats['Price'] = drop_boats['Price'] * 0.15 
elif drop_boats['Currency'] == 'Â£':
    drop_boats['Price'] = drop_boats['Price'] * 1.32
else:
     drop_boats['Price' ]= drop_boats['Price']
```

I'm getting this error: `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`.

Comment: Please post your entire code along with a sample of your dataframe.

Comment: You are trying to make comparison on a df column. You should make a for loop over dataframe rows.

Comment: That fact that you are comparing against `'Â£'` in one case means you have an encoding error somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iter over the pandas rows using `iter.rows()` and carry the calculation. Refer the below code:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Currency'] == 'EUR':
        row['Price'] = row['Price'] * 1.10 
    elif row['Currency'] == 'CHF':
        row['Price'] = row['Price'] * 1.08 
    elif row['Currency'] == 'DKK':
        row['Price'] = row['Price'] * 0.15 
    elif row['Currency'] == 'Â£':
        row['Price'] = row['Price'] * 1.32
    else:
        row['Price' ]= row['Price']
```

Comment: Why the iteration?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `loc` with boolean indexing. If not show sample input and output data, please.

```
drop_boats.loc[drop_boats['Currency'].eq('EUR'), 'Price'] *= 1.10
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish what you want is like this:

```
for index, row in drop_boats.iterrows():
  if row['Currency'] == 'EUR':
    drop_boats.loc[index, 'Price'] = row['Price'] * 1.10
```

You can add your other conditions accordingly...